# Alternative for Conversational actions

Tags: actions-on-google

Currently we have actions, which are built with Conversational Fulfillment type and Dialog Flow as fulfillment tool. Thereby allowing the users to communicate with our service using Google assistant supported devices.

Our web service received a POST request from Dialogflow in the form of the response to a user query matched by intents with webhook enabled.

https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000b9b04da80c?hl=en
https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/00000019f080cfcd?hl=en
These links  provide details about the sample utterances which we were able to support from google assistant.

As Conversational actions will be removed by June, please advise about the  alternative for this action.

App actions  cannot be used as it requires Android app for launching.Also as written in the deprecation best practices (https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset/best-practices) Smart Home can only be added to compatible devices.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) is one of the ways to interact with Assistant without a screen. It lets you add voice control, natural language understanding to your project. Your project captures an utterance, sends it to the Google Assistant, and receives a spoken audio response in addition to the raw text of the utterance. However, this won't provide a way to create custom responses, or control what the assistant gives back as a response.